# This command cannot be run due to the error: Access is denied

Tags: powershell, zabbix

I Have an application running on windows server 2019 and Zabbix to monitor that process. I have a powershell script that Zabbix run if the app crash but is not working I get the error
"This command cannot be run due to the error: Access is denied."

My script neeeds to send a number and press ENTER to run the app.

```
Start-Process "c:\my_app.exe"
Start-Sleep -s 1
$obj = new-object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$obj.SendKeys("3")
Start-Sleep -s 1
$obj.SendKeys("{ENTER}")
```

Anyone have a similar situation that works?

Answer (score 0):

More information would help tbh. Is that script triggered by a scheduled task?
I'd go about trying to debug this as follows:

Devise your script into 2 parts.

1. Part 1 : Start the process
2. Part 2 : Test if the SendKeys() work

Test each part individually.

My guess is that the user-context you are running your script in, does not have sufficient permissions to start that process. Maybe it has no access to the path?
Chances of you not having permission to send a key, are low i'd say.

Comment: "triggered by a scheduled task" No, is trigger by zabbix agente when it see is down.

Comment: On my Zabbix server, I have an action to see if the process is running every 10 minutes if is down it runs: powershell.exe -Command "&'C:\my_script.ps1'"

Comment: Yeah so, the context of your Zabbix service doesn't have permission to your scriptpath OR isn't allowed to run scripts. Just as a test, add that user\service-account to the local admingroup and see if it works that way.

Comment: my zabbix agent service as log on as admin account and I found that the service run in background but doesn't open the APP

Answer (score 0):

Even if I run the script through task scheduler we run the process but in background the window doesn't open.

a script like this one (my_scrip.ps1)

```
start-process "notepad"
start-sleep 3
$obj = new-object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$obj.SendKeys("3")
start-sleep 3
$obj.SendKeys("{ENTER}")
```

running in powershell or through task scheduler is totaly difference

Comment: The window will not show up if the schedule task is running under a different username.

Comment: I'm running with same user and with high privileges I have to save the task with username and password

Comment: Did you select "Interact with Desktop" in the Task Scheduler?

Comment: I don't have that option